# Objective C - app works in simulator and on other iPhones, but won't run on my own iPhone 4

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, ios-simulator, ccsprite

My app works fine in the simulator, and on other devices.  I have an iPhone 4 with the latest iOS update, and the app refuses to run on my device.

It seems to be a problem surrounding retina-display images.  The error spew I get when attempting to run on the phone is:

```
2012-01-11 09:27:47.404 rr_game1[1569:707] cocos2d: cocos2d v1.0.1
2012-01-11 09:27:47.413 rr_game1[1569:707] cocos2d: Using Director Type:CCDirectorDisplayLink
2012-01-11 09:27:47.845 rr_game1[1569:707] cocos2d: OS version: 5.0.1 (0x05000100)
2012-01-11 09:27:47.849 rr_game1[1569:707] cocos2d: GL_VENDOR:   Imagination Technologies
2012-01-11 09:27:47.853 rr_game1[1569:707] cocos2d: GL_RENDERER: PowerVR SGX 535
2012-01-11 09:27:47.856 rr_game1[1569:707] cocos2d: GL_VERSION:  OpenGL ES-CM 1.1 IMGSGX535-63.14.2
2012-01-11 09:27:47.861 rr_game1[1569:707] cocos2d: GL_MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE: 2048
2012-01-11 09:27:47.864 rr_game1[1569:707] cocos2d: GL_MAX_MODELVIEW_STACK_DEPTH: 16
2012-01-11 09:27:47.867 rr_game1[1569:707] cocos2d: GL_MAX_SAMPLES: 4
2012-01-11 09:27:47.871 rr_game1[1569:707] cocos2d: GL supports PVRTC: YES
2012-01-11 09:27:47.874 rr_game1[1569:707] cocos2d: GL supports BGRA8888 textures: YES
2012-01-11 09:27:47.877 rr_game1[1569:707] cocos2d: GL supports NPOT textures: YES
2012-01-11 09:27:47.880 rr_game1[1569:707] cocos2d: GL supports discard_framebuffer: YES
2012-01-11 09:27:47.883 rr_game1[1569:707] cocos2d: compiled with NPOT support: NO
2012-01-11 09:27:47.886 rr_game1[1569:707] cocos2d: compiled with VBO support in TextureAtlas : YES
2012-01-11 09:27:47.889 rr_game1[1569:707] cocos2d: compiled with Affine Matrix transformation in CCNode : YES
2012-01-11 09:27:47.892 rr_game1[1569:707] cocos2d: compiled with Profiling Support: NO
2012-01-11 09:27:48.012 rr_game1[1569:707] Game manager singleton, init
2012-01-11 09:27:48.031 rr_game1[1569:707] cocos2d: WARNING: Image (1024 x 4096) is bigger than the supported 2048 x 2048
2012-01-11 09:27:48.035 rr_game1[1569:707] cocos2d: Couldn't add image:grid.png in CCTextureCache
2012-01-11 09:27:48.047 rr_game1[1569:707] cocos2d: WARNING: Image (1024 x 4096) is bigger than the supported 2048 x 2048
2012-01-11 09:27:48.050 rr_game1[1569:707] cocos2d: Couldn't add image:bg-circuits.png in CCTextureCache
2012-01-11 09:27:48.054 rr_game1[1569:707] *** Assertion failure in -[CCParallaxNode addChild:z:parallaxRatio:positionOffset:], /Users/kevin/code/rr_game1/rr_game1/libs/cocos2d/CCParallaxNode.m:91
2012-01-11 09:27:48.058 rr_game1[1569:707] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Argument must be non-nil'
```

The odd thing is that the images it is puking on are in the app.

[image: Screenshot of resources dir]

Again, the app works on other devices and in the simulator.  Here is the code that loads the images:

```
backgroundNode = [CCParallaxNode node];
[self addChild:_backgroundNode z:-1];

_backgroundGrid1 = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"grid.png"];
_backgroundCircuits1 = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"bg-circuits.png"];

_backgroundGrid1.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0,0);
_backgroundCircuits1.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0,0);
CGPoint gridSpeed = ccp(0.05, 0.05);
CGPoint circuitSpeed = ccp(0.1, 0.1);

[_backgroundNode addChild:_backgroundGrid1 z:1 parallaxRatio:gridSpeed positionOffset:ccp(0,-winSize.height)];
[_backgroundNode addChild:_backgroundCircuits1 z:0 parallaxRatio:circuitSpeed positionOffset:ccp(0,-winSize.height)];
```

I've deleted the app from my phone, run a "clean," restarted Xcode, and restarted my computer.  Still no luck.  I've also re-provisioned my phone.  I've also deleted and re-added the assets to the project.

Comment: It says the image is to big. It's just strange that, that only happens with the iPhone 4...

Comment: Don't use the @2x extension with cocos2d. Use the -hd suffix instead. See: http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/wiki/doku.php/prog_guide:how_to_develop_retinadisplay_games_in_cocos2d

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be honest, it does say within your log file that the image size of 1024 x 4096 is far greater than the supported 2048 x 2048:

```
2012-01-11 09:27:48.031 rr_game1[1569:707] cocos2d: WARNING: Image (1024 x 4096) is bigger than the supported 2048 x 2048
2012-01-11 09:27:48.035 rr_game1[1569:707] cocos2d: Couldn't add image:grid.png in CCTextureCache
2012-01-11 09:27:48.047 rr_game1[1569:707] cocos2d: WARNING: Image (1024 x 4096) is bigger than the supported 2048 x 2048
2012-01-11 09:27:48.050 rr_game1[1569:707] cocos2d: Couldn't add image:bg-circuits.png in CCTextureCache
```

You say it runs on other devices but what devices are they? If they are not retina enabled, I imagine the respective image size would be 512x2048 thus fitting the 2048x2048 maximum size.

If your retina-display images are beyond those dimensions, it simply will not work - the 2048x2048 should already encompass the retina-sized images. You may need to revise your game to use smaller dimensions.

Comment: Or the other devices may have been iPhone 4Ss, maybe? Maximum texture size has gone up to 4096x4096 on those. Also, if backwards compatibility is a concern then it's worth being aware that it was 1024x1024 on all the PowerVR MBX devices (ie, the iPhone, iPhone 3G and associated iPods).

Comment: One of the other devices is another regular iPhone 4, as well as an iPhone 4s.

Comment: Just did some more digging - the file it's having a problem with isn't 1024x4096 - it's 640x2292

Comment: Oddly, even though it works as-is on another iPhone 4, reducing the file size to 640x2048 fixed the problem on _my_ device.

Answer (score 2):

You should really look into cutting down your images into smaller chunks and possibly placing them in a sprite sheet for performance. Then you can simply add the images slices next to each other using something like this

```
    for (int i = 0; i < amountOfSprites; i++){
        CCSprite *sprite = [CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:spriteName];
        sprite.anchorPoint = ccp(0,0);

        sprite.position = ccp((i * sprite.contentSize.width),0);


        [yourBatchNode addChild:sprite];
    }
```

if you need any help with creating sprite sheets check out this guide http://www.raywenderlich.com/2361/how-to-create-and-optimize-sprite-sheets-in-cocos2d-with-texture-packer-and-pixel-formats